# Custom keyboard config stopped working for spacebar only after upgrading Fedora 34 ￫ 36

Tags: fedora, keyboard-layout

**Context**
I have a [custom keyboard config](https://github.com/EBoisseauSierra/bepo_ebosi/blob/master/fr_bepo_ebosi). It worked like a charm on Fedora 34.
I have just upgraded to Fedora 36 and reinstalled the keyboard layout.

**Issue**
The custom layout is picked up, except for [the `<SPCE>` (space bar) key definition](https://github.com/EBoisseauSierra/bepo_ebosi/blob/master/fr_bepo_ebosi#L92):

```
key <SPCE> { [ space, nobreakspace, underscore, U202F ] }; // ␣ (espace insécable) _ (espace insécable fin)
```

The concrete issue is that **only a regular space is printed when pressing <kbd>spacebar</kbd>** (i.e., the modifiers — <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>/Level 3 shift — aren't effective); instead of, notably, an underscore (`_`) when pressing <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>spacebar</kbd>.

Yet at the same time, I can get <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> to work with the other keys (i.e. <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>`<AD01>`</kbd> does [print `|`](https://github.com/EBoisseauSierra/bepo_ebosi/blob/master/fr_bepo_ebosi#L53) as expected).
I have tried to move the `key <SPCE>` definition in an other position within the `xkb_symbols {}` block without success.
I have also looked at other (embedded) keyboard definitions and can't seem to find that something has changed…

**Question**
How to fix my `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/fr` definition so that modifiers are applied to the <kbd>spacebar</kbd>?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by adding the `type[group1] = "FOUR_LEVEL_SEMIALPHABETIC"` modifier to the <kbd>spacebar</kbd> definition as follows:

```
key <SPCE> { type[group1] = "FOUR_LEVEL_SEMIALPHABETIC", [ space, nobreakspace, underscore, U202F ] };
```

<sub>(Note that the no-break space ([U+00A0](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00A0)) isn't working… but at least I got the underscore back!)</sub>